# How to remove a region of an image to leave the surrounding space in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, watermark

So if I have a grayscale image_I, I need to remove a region_R from it to leave the surrounding space.

So far I have got

```
region_R = image_I(regionStartPoint(1):regionStartPoint(1)+size_W(1)-1,...
                   regionStartPoint(2):regionStartPoint(2)+size_W(2)-1);
```

`surroundingSpace = image_I - region_R`

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

If by removing, you mean making it to 0 or 1, than you can simply do as follows:

```
image_I(regionStartPoint(1):regionStartPoint(1)+size_W(1)-1,...
                   regionStartPoint(2):regionStartPoint(2)+size_W(2)-1) = 0
```

Or you can assign NaN to it,

```
image_I(regionStartPoint(1):regionStartPoint(1)+size_W(1)-1,...
                   regionStartPoint(2):regionStartPoint(2)+size_W(2)-1) = NaN
```

Comment: So I have a manipulation on the region, and I also have a manipulation on the surrounding space. The region needs not interfere with the surrounding space manipulation. Thanks

Comment: @conapart3 I don't understand your statement. What Marcin suggested should work and that's what I understood your problem description as.

Comment: The manipulation will spread the bits from a bit plane in region_R throughout the whole image. The region_R area on the image will then get overwritten by the watermark pixels. I don't want this information to be saved in the image where region_R is as it will get overwritten. If I make the whole of region_R 0, then my understanding is that it will still get overwritten? So formally I need to manipulate only the surrounding space which is image_I - region_R. I will try these and see, and further understand what I need to do. Thanks!

Comment: I = (I - R) ∪ R and (I - R) ∩ R = ∅

Comment: In simple words, I is the set of all pixels in the image, R contains the set of pixels from the selected rectangular area and I-R contains the set of the remaining pixels. R and I-R are exclusive because different operations will be done on them. He has already extracted R with `region_R`. He can then set that region in `image_I` to NaN, just as you described so that when he works on it, he can ignore any NaN elements. NaN is more preferable as the value to ignore than 0, because he's working with pixel values.